# MacBook Pro charge cycle counter in battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

In a MacBook Pro, is the counter for charge cycles in the battery or in the motherboard?   (I'm thinking it should be in the battery, but I've taken apart a MacBook Air, and those batteries don't appear to have any place to put a counter.)

Comment: Did you already see this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96668/does-the-macbook-battery-cycle-count-reset-when-replacing-a-battery

Comment: NOT an exact duplicate, but it does contain the answer.  Unfortunately, the suggested questions cannot scroll in the iPad app.